# Distributed database in Azure Sql Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are currently using Azure SQL Database in Desktop/Web application and is hosted in South East Asia. For the Web/Mobile, I have hosted the App Service in South East Asia as well but Windows application we have designed it to directly call database.

Until now there was no issue in performance, connectivity. But recently our company has expanded its operations in Russia. So we have users using the Desktop application in Russia and they are currently facing very slow connection as each and every query has to travel until South East Asia which is affecting the usability of the application and sometimes the users have to wait more than 1-2 mins to see the query result.

My question here is how can improve this without modifying much code in my application? One thing I can do is the geo-replication but the secondary database here will be read-only and I cannot use this for edit/update operations. Is there is any other possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into Azure SQL Data Sync. It's a service that allows synchronizing data across multiple Azure SQL databases as well as on-prem instances. There is lots of info online, but this should get you started.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-sql-data-sync/